# On OkCupid, how can I search through questions I haven't answered?

Tags: search, okcupid

I sometimes use [OkCupid](http://www.okcupid.com/), a dating/friend-finding site. It works by matching up users based on their answers to a series of questions. But when I search through the set of available questions, the site searches only through the text of the questions I've already answered.

How can I search through the text of all the site's questions, including the questions I haven't answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a couple of possible solutions. The best one I've found is to search through [the set of questions answered by someone who's answered several thousand questions](http://www.okcupid.com/profile/dvdphn/questions).